# Converting JSON between Haneke and SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, cocoa-touch

I'm attempting to take some JSON returned by Alamofire (from an API request) and set/fetch it using Haneke as my cache.

I have originally casted the JSON object in SwiftyJSON to parse for immediate use, but I am having trouble getting it to store in the Haneke cache.

It seems that SwiftyJSON and Haneke have two separate JSON types, and I cannot figure out how to cast one to another.

Here's an example of attempting to cast the returned SwiftyJSON object to Haneke:

```
        let cache = Shared.JSONCache

        if let cachedJson: Haneke.JSON = json! {
            cache.set(value: json!, key: "pageContent")
        }
```

But I receive the following error:

> 'JSON' is not convertible to 'JSON'

Any ideas what can be done about this? I've attempted to cast the JSON from Alamofire directly to the Haneke JSON type but I cannot seem to get that to work either...

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
if let cachedJson: Haneke.JSON = json {
    cache.set(value: cachedJson, key: "pageContent")
}
```

You just need to replace json with cachedJson. `if let` checks for the `nil` values as well.